# How to convert query object into a List of Strings?

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I got a Login class:

```
if((!(name.equals(null) || name.equals("")) && !(password.equals(null) ||  password.equals(""))))
        {
            try{
                loggedUser = checkLogin(name, hexPass.toString());

                if(!loggedUser.isEmpty())
                {
                    userdbId = loggedUser.get(0);
                    userdbName = loggedUser.get(1);
                    userdbPsw = loggedUser.get(2);
                    userdbType = loggedUser.get(3);

                    ...
```

And a user DAO:

```
public List<String> checkLogin(String uname, String password) {
    Session session = null;
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        session = getSession();
        String sql = "select * from user where uname='" + uname + "' and password='" + password + "'";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                .addScalar("Id", StringType.INSTANCE)
                .addScalar("uname", StringType.INSTANCE) 
                .addScalar("password", StringType.INSTANCE) 
                .addScalar("utype", StringType.INSTANCE);
        lst = query.list();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lst;
}
```

The userdbId = loggedUser.get(0); generates error: 500

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
com.se.pl.actions.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:95)
```

I do not understand why this is happening since list of 4 strings is going to be put into 4 variables.

Comment: With that code you won't get List of Strings but List of Objects with four properties.

Comment: Could you tell us if you use ORM framework and if you do then which type and version?

Comment: Can you give me advice on how to make this work as expected? I am a noob programmer.

Comment: @fallenPhantasm I do not use this framework

Comment: it seems you use Hibernate ORM framework

Comment: @Nailgun: Yes, but what is the reason you ask?

Comment: @TheKolanN if you want your question to be answered it is better to provide as more details as you can. Nobody can just make your peace of code work.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have an Object and you are doing an implicit cast to String, so that's the error.

```
userdbId = loggedUser.get(0);
```

You can fix that by adding toString() method like:

```
userdbId = loggedUser.get(0).toString();
```

Of course, you are going to get the string representation for that object.

Note that if you have your own object you are going to get the following representation:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

In case you have this, you will need to override the `toString()` method in your class

Comment: userdbId = loggedUser.get(0).toString(); do not work, because the user is nested in the first object in the list and I cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TypedQuery<T>` instead of query and create objects of user entity type(if you have it defined - you definitely should have one) - it should look something like this (**do not take this code literaly! I mainly use OpenJPA**)

```
TypedQuery<UserEntity> query= session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE name=:name AND password=:password");
query.addParam("name",name);
query.addParam("password",password);
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably should help:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                .addScalar("Id", StringType.INSTANCE)
                .addScalar("uname", StringType.INSTANCE) 
                .addScalar("password", StringType.INSTANCE) 
                .addScalar("utype", StringType.INSTANCE)
                .setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

Map row = (Map) query.uniqueResult();
lst.add((String) row.get("Id"));
lst.add((String) row.get("uname"));
lst.add((String) row.get("password"));
lst.add((String) row.get("utype"));
```

Comment: I get the following error: (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: @TheKolanN I added `.setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);` Please try again